# Extruding, right-clicking, then scaling moves some vertices to the wrong place

Tags: modeling, extrude, scale

Here's the image:

[image: Some vertices are in the wrong place]

It starts like this before I perform the procedures in the title:

[image: A plain cylinder]

Here's the file: [image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In the Tool region > Options, you have 'X-Mirror' turned on.. as a side-note, you may have to watch out for the discontinuities in the edge-loop above this one, eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Tool* panel (on the left of your 3D View window, activated with <kbd>T</kbd>) > *Options* tab, deactivate the *Mirror* option.

[image]